# How can I change the TAX rule when customer chooses to pick the item up in store from a non-EU country? Magento 2.4

Tags: tax-class, store-pickup

We are located in The Netherlands, where the tax rate is 21%. We ship to The USA (outside EU) where we do not need to include any taxes. This has been set up in the tax rules. But when a customer from The USA enters their country and says they would like to pick it up in our store we are obliged to charge the 21%. How can I do this?

We are using Magento 2.4.